# Intel HD Graphics 530 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, lenovo, intel

I have Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit installed on my Lenovo Ideapad 700-15 isk. Which has integrated video card Intel HD Graphics and NVIDIA Geforce 950M. So, I can say that now it doesn't feel so good as I thought it will be. It's like a little bit laggy and feels slow.

Should I switch to an NVIDIA driver, and if so, then how?

Answer (score 1):

To install **Nvidia Drivers**:

You can use Software & Updates application where you have to just navigate to **Additional Drivers** section where you will see something like this

[image]

Just select the appropriate version of nvidia driver and click on apply changes after installing the drivers you might need to restart your pc.

**Alternatively,** you can install using third party `ppa` using following commands:

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390
```

If you'd like to check available versions of nvidia drivers just press the **Tab** button after typing the following command:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-
```

**Note**: To check if the nvidia drivers are installed or not you can run the following command and you'll see something like this

```
nvidia-smi
```

[image]

Happy Ubuntu!

Comment: "you can run the following command": which one? I can't see it in your post

Comment: Okay good caught, I am just edit my answer

Comment: IMO you should reverse the order of your solutions, IIUC the second one is supported by Ubuntu, whereas the other relies on a third party (the ppa).

Answer (score -1):

Open the app drawer and search for "drivers", open the app and install the Nvidia Graphics Driver. Just be aware that it will use more battery power.

Comment: Hi Zastian - put yourself in the position of the Asker... does he know what the app drawer is or to open it? Have you verified that this is enough detail and accurate to solve the problem? Add some more details to your answer if you can.